# How to cast PC (win8) display to Samsung Smart TV?

Tags: windows-8

Is there a way to cast a PC display to Samsung Smart TV over ethernet? Both devices are on the same network.

Comment: Does the TV support Android TV?

Comment: Does the Samsung Smart TV understand ChromeCast, or does it have its own casting method? If it has a buildin chromecast, you can cast your desktop from Google Chrome.

Comment: @hardillb I will have to check on that. At the moment it has it's own Samsung Smart TV OS with different apps (youtube, netflix etc)

Comment: @LPChip no, it doesn't have chromecast, something called AllShare from what I can see

Comment: If your computer supports Miracast, yes. If not, no.

Answer (score 1):

Think it's possible to do this with **Miracast** (wireless technology used for mirroring the screen of your PC to your TV). The TV must support Miracast, otherwise you have to buy a Miracast adapter. 
If your PC supports Miracast, you can try to search for '**Devices**' in settings and then '**Add a wireless monitor**'.

Comment: This is, more or less, the correct answer. Samsung devices have a Miracast derivative. If the computer supports Miracast, you'll be able to display on the TV. If not, no.